# How to include plist file in the php page?

Tags: php, plist, ota

I am using the following code

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?php
include('app.plist');
?>`

But ITMS service is not working on this file.

I want that ITMS service should behave like it usually do when we use plist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749599/how-to-parse-a-plist-file-with-php

Comment: I want to have a php page behave as a plist file.

Comment: What do you exactly need ? Having .plist file generated by php so you could access http://randomness.com/info.plist and get php generated code. Or what do you exactly want ?

Comment: Already we have a plist. Want to include it to the php page and ITMS should work on that php page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to force webserver to process .plist as an PHP script. I suggest using RewriteMod by writing file with name .htaccess to folder containing these files. Note, that webserver must support .htaccess processing - most of servers do. Try consulting google about mod_rewrite and here is an example configuration that you would put to .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.plist$ /plistgen.php [L,QSA]
```

To file plistgen.php write:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <?php include('app.plist'); ?>
```

Then when you call for example http://yourweb.tld/Random.plist it automatically calls plistgen.php and your script is being processed.